# BlackBerry SQLite database creation: "filesystem not ready"

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

My application takes data from a server and saves it to an SQLite database. This works fine in the 9550 ([BlackBerry Storm 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_Storm_2)) simulator, but when I run this in any other simulator it gives me this error:

> file system not ready

Code snippet:

```
URI myURI = URI.create("file:///store/MyDataBase.db");
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Open a FileConnection to that URI and see if canWrite() returns true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be that store is not a mounted and available file system root on the 9550. You should use javax.microedition.io.file.FileSystemRegistry.listRoots() to get an Enumeration of currently mounted file systems.

Comment: i tried this and i found that store is available file system in each emulator. than why this file system not ready error accurs??

Answer (score 23):

Richard is right. You need to check for the existence of the filesystem root "store".  There is an extra wrinkle for using SQLite, though. [RIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_In_Motion) only supports SQLite on [eMMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiMediaCard) storage. So even if "store" exists, it will only work if the underlying storage is eMMC. Notably the [BlackBerry Bold 9650](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_Bold#BlackBerry_Bold_9650) device, AKA Bold2, has "store", but it is not eMMC, so you can't put an SQLite database there.

I'm not aware of any direct way of finding out whether a filesystem is using eMMC. I asked RIM and was told to check the filesystem size. If it's over 1 GB, then it is eMMC.   That wasn't a very satisfying answer for me. I ended up checking for the filesystem "system". It is a read-only filesystem, but it is only present for eMMC storage, and if it exists, you can write a database to the "store" filesystem root.

Via the [SQLite developer guide overview](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11945/SQLite_714136_11.jsp):

> You can use the SQLite API, provided in the `net.rim.device.api.database` package, to store application data persistently to eMMC memory or a microSD card.

Comment: Michael, I've got to say you've got further than me on this one. Big surprise when I found I couldn't write to the /store even though it exists - and only on certain devices. This means SQLite databases are only available without SDCards on certain devices. Fun.

Comment: Michael...But Sqlite is used only in BlackBerry devices that run BlackBerry® Device Software 5.0 or later include the SQLite library.   what about device software below 5.0. can't we use sqlite for them?? if we can't than what is the alternete??

Comment: @nimi that question would be better handled by creating a new question on StackOverflow, after searching for any existing questions that might be similar.

Comment: Michael - great explaination and research.  Thank you.