# SqLite database on device storage for BlackBerry

Tags: database, sqlite, blackberry, database-connection

I am trying to create a database in the device storage of a BlackBerry simulator.
In the 9500 simulator, the database is created successfully but creating a table results in a "File System error" message.  On the 9700 simulator, the database fails at the creation step.

Is there a single code sequence which will create a database for all simulators?

I have written the following code:

```
uri = URI.create("file:///store/home/user/Databases/xtc.db");
xtcDB = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
createTblQurey.append("CREATE TABLE MESSENGER_USERS");
createTblQurey.append("(");
createTblQurey.append("USERID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,");
createTblQurey.append("USERNAME TEXT NOT NULL,");
createTblQurey.append("DISPLAYNAME TEXT NOT NULL,");
createTblQurey.append("ISREGISTERED CHARACTER DEFAULT 'N'");
createTblQurey.append(")");

stmt = xtcDB.createStatement(createTblQurey.toString());
stmt.prepare();
stmt.execute();
Debugger.debug(UrlInfo.workflow_File,"MESSENGER_USERS table created successfully...!!!");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [BlackBerry SqLite db creation: "filesystem not ready"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447526/blackberry-sqlite-db-creation-filesystem-not-ready)

Answer (score 2):

Only following list of BB devices supports SQLite database in device memory that has at least 1 GB of eMMC memory.

Blackberry Bold 9000
Torch 9800
BlackBerry Storm 9500
BlackBerry Storm 2 9550
Blackberry Storm 2 9520

That is the reason why you got error.