# Which Blackberry devices support SQLite only on SDCard?

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, sd-card

I would like to know which BB devices support SQLite only on SDCard. I know for example, that 9700 Bold only supports SQLite on SDCard but not in device memory.

I would like to have a list like:

```
Device | SQLite on SDCard | SQLite in device memory

9700   |        x         |
xxxx   |        x         |            x
```

Probably such a list doesn't exist :-)

But maybe some of you have at least experiences with some devices and can tell me what kind of SQlite location they support.

Thanks

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489940/sqlite-database-on-device-storage-for-blackberry