# BlackBerry SQLite supported devices

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, blackberry-jde

We can create a SQLite database on 5.0, 6.0 and 7.0 devices. Does anybody knows which blackberry devices supports creating and managing SQLite databasse on internal memory (eMMC memory)?

As of now I've come to know that BlackBerry 9700 and 9650 do not support creating a SQLite database on internal memory (`///store` path). Apart from this, is there is any other device out there?

And also, I heard that a device which has less than 1GB internal memory will not support creating a SQLite database in internal memory; is that true? There are no documents available to clearly explain this (?)

Comment: You can add the 8520 and 9300 to your list of non-eMMC devices.  I am not aware of a comprehensive list anywhere.

Comment: Just adding link to a related question that Michael has contributed a great answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447526/blackberry-sqlite-database-creation-filesystem-not-ready/4451954#4451954

Answer (score -1):

Only following list of BB devices supports SQLite database in device memory that has at least 1 GB of eMMC memory.

- Blackberry Bold 9000
- Torch 9800
- BlackBerry Storm 9500
- BlackBerry Storm 2 9550
- Blackberry Storm 2 9520.

Comment: This seems to be a copy of the answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489940/sqlite-database-on-device-storage-for-blackberry and is at least 2 years old.  I don't have a more up-to-date list, but the question I have already linked to provides a more useful answer.