# Database not working in phone memory works fine with SDCard in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am building an  Blackberry application in which I am creating a database as the application launches . The problem is that the code works fine with sdCard but but when i am removing the SDCard and trying to use Phone Memory , its not working.
Here is the code I am using to create the database:

```
public static String db_location="file:///SDCard/Databases/MyApp/MyDatabase.db";

    public MyDatabase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

         boolean sdCardPresent = false;
            String root = null;
            Enumeration e = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
            while (e.hasMoreElements())
            {
                root = (String)e.nextElement();
                if(root.equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard/"))
                {
                    sdCardPresent = true;


                }     
            }            
            if(!sdCardPresent)
            {
                // If an SDCard is not available we will store our database in
                // flash memory.  This is not recommended for large databases.

                db_location = "file:///store/home/user/Databases/MyApp/MyDatabase.db";   

            }          
        try
           {


         URI myURI = URI.create(db_location); 
         d = DatabaseFactory.create(myURI);

    d.close();
     }
     catch ( Exception e1 ) 
     {         
         System.out.println( e1.getMessage() );
         e1.printStackTrace();
     }


    }
```

Please suggest

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447526/blackberry-sqlite-db-creation-filesystem-not-ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlackBerry supports saving SQLite databases in eMMC memory (**/store**) only on certain models.

For example, BlackBerry Curve 8520 (which you seem to have) does not support saving SQLite database in **/store** (only in **/SDCard**).

Comment: Is there any prblm in coding.. ?...ya i have 8520 curve