# SD Card usage is essential for "database.db" file in my application in blackberry?

Tags: database, blackberry, sd-card

I am working on Blackberry database dependent application. On click of button i just show some useful data on other screen by fetching data from .db file stored in my sd card. Initially I provide that ".db" file from my ASSETS.

Now, i have seen some users review, they are getting problem in using SD-Card.

My question is "Is is possible to use sql database/.db file without using SD-Card in my application in blackberry"
Please let me know if it is possible....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separated filesystems supported. The first - internal device filesystem, the second - memory sd card filesystem.

Internal device filesystem does not depend on memory sd card and it is possible to create file there. But note that if your database consumes all available internal memory then device becomes mad.

Internal memory is an important resource to support vital operating system activies and when there is a shortage of this kind of memory then weird things occur, like sudden restarts, freezing issues etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit more complicated than just having write access to the filesystem.  Only certain types of internal storage support SqLite.  See [BlackBerry SqLite db creation: “filesystem not ready”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447526/blackberry-sqlite-db-creation-filesystem-not-ready/4451954#4451954)