# how to create database in blackberry mobile

Tags: blackberry

1. List item

   i developed an application , in which uses sq lite database . this is running properly on simulater  . but when we application deploy on Blackberry curve 8520 mobile then . tell us database does not exist.  anyone know answer please quick response ...

My Code is ->

```java
public static void insertData( String pass , String cpass)
{
    boolean fl=false;
    String root = null;
    MainScreen ms = new MainScreen();
    Enumeration e = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
    while (e.hasMoreElements())
    {
        root = (String)e.nextElement();
        if(root.equalsIgnoreCase("store/"))
        {
            fl=true;
        }
    }
    if(!fl)
    {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Dialog.alert("This application requires an SD card to be present." + 
                             "Exiting application...");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        String dbLocation = "C:/om12345/sql/res/store/";
        // Create URI
        // Statement st=null;
        try
        {
            URI myURI = URI.create("file:///store/home/user/databases/database.sqlite");
            //URI myURI1=URI.
            d = DatabaseFactory.create(myURI);
            Statement st = d.createStatement( "insert into Admin (pass, Cpass) values('"+ pass+"','"+cpass+"')");
            st.prepare();
            st.execute();
            st.close();
            d.close();
            //ms.add(new RichTextField ("tata" + "tata1"));
            // UiApplication.getApplication.invokeLater(pushScreeen(ms));
        }
        catch ( Exception e1 )
        {
            System.out.println( e1.getMessage() );
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely can't store a sqlite database on `/store` for the 8520.  See my answer to [BlackBerry SQLite database creation: "filesystem not ready"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447526/blackberry-sqlite-db-creation-filesystem-not-ready/4451954#4451954) for more information on that.

Comment: but do you know , this is store data .so, how can i accept that think.

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to change the line that says " String dbLocation = "C:/om12345/sql/res/store/";" since that refers to a location on your development machine but will not work on a mobile device.  You need to point to the 'res' folder in your application itself.

Comment: The code could use some cleaning. The dbLocation string isn't being passed to DatabaseFactory.create(), so that recommendation isn't going to help.

Comment: please , you give proper ans of this problem. as database path

Comment: i wanna say that can you tell me step by step solution of this problem.please.....

Answer (score 0):

You can not create database into store directory if you are having less than 1gb internal storage & you have saved your data base in C directory , which can be accessible from your system, but not on device. So change its location copied into it res folder. 
& check if you are having SD card then save your database using /SDCard.
If SDCard is not available than you will able to access database , if you are having more than 1GB internal storage
have a look on this link

```
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/SQLite_database_files_1219778_11.jsp
```