# How to get SD card events?

Tags: java, blackberry

I'm building an app that monitors phone usage. I need to implement an SQLite db that is necessary for the application running.

Because not all devices have an eMMC, I need to check if the device have the eMMC and if not I need to check if an SD card is available. (If an eMMC is not present, the only other place where blackberry let me put the db is the SD card).

I need to know how to check if the SD card is present and how many free space it has and then I need to implement a "listener" to check hot SD removal event and similar.

Someone can help?

Thanks.

Comment: See answers [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4447526/119114).

Comment: @Nate Thank you for your comment, but I sow this before post my question and it didn't provide an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FileSystemRegistry](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileSystemRegistry.html) has a static method where you can add a custom [FileSystemListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileSystemListener.html) implementation. This will let you know when the SD card is added or removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I need. Do you know if there is a way to check at application start if the SD is present, before start the listener?

Comment: Sorry, I have the answer, just call the method listRoots() of FileSystemRegistry and check for "SDCard/".
Thank you again.